# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Message=Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')

Tags: c#, parsing

Why is this code giving me a "length cannot be less than zero" error message?

```
class Fraction
     {
         private double Numerator = 0;
         private double Denominator= 1;

         public static Fraction Parse(string str)
         {
             Fraction newFrac = new Fraction();

             int indexSlash = str.IndexOf("/");
             newFrac.Numerator = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, indexSlash));
             newFrac.Denominator = int.Parse(str.Substring(indexSlash + 1));

             return newFrac;
         }
     }
```

Comment: `str` does not have the character `/` in it, so `indexSlash` is -1.

Comment: If `str` *doesn't contain* `/` then `str.IndexOf("/");` returns `-1`  (so `indexSlash == -1`) and `str.Substring(0, indexSlash)` throws the exception

Comment: It would be helpful to show what you're passing into that `Parse()` method to know for sure, but it sounds like the cause is what everyone is saying. You're fraction has no `/` character, thus it's returning `-1`.

Comment: Well, use the debugger to single-step through your code and watch the values of your variables. If you do that, you'll notice that _indexSlash_ indeed will be less than zero. Why, you ask? Well, look up the official documentation for string.IndexOf, it explains this...

Answer (score 3):

`string.IndexOf()` returns -1 when the string does not contain the expected sequence (a slash in this case). So when you call `Parse()` with a string that does not contain a slash ("/"), the next line calls `str.Substring(0, -1)`, which is obviously illegal.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the message is that `str` doesn't contain `/`:

```
// when str doesn't contain "/", the result of IndexOf is -1
// So indexSlash == -1 
int indexSlash = str.IndexOf("/");
// str.Substring(0, indexSlash)
//   is now
// str.Substring(0, -1)
//   which throws the exception
newFrac.Numerator = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, indexSlash));
```

I suggest starting implementation from `TryParse`:

```
class Fraction {
  ...
  public static bool TryParse(string value, out Fraction result) {
    result = null;

    if (value is null)
      return false;

    int index = value.IndexOf('/');

    if (index <= 0)
      return false;

    if (!int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, index), out var num) || 
        !int.TryParse(str.Substring(index + 1), out var den))
      return false;

    result = new Fraction() {
      Numerator   = num, 
      Denominator = den
    };

    return true;
  }
```

And based on it `Parse` which is very simple now:

```
  public static Fraction Parse(string value) => TryParse(value, out var result)
    ? result
    : throw new FormatException("Not a valid format for fraction");
```

Comment: I think it can be argued whether a string without a / is by definition illegal. It could be valid to specify a number without a Denominator (which equals to a denominator of 1)